# Problem trying to install pillow 5.3.0 for python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-imaging-library

My system is:

**Win 10 64 bit**

I'm trying to install Pillow for python but I can never do it, I'm new to this stuff.

I downloaded the wheel for 5.3.0 because I have 3.7, then I try to install but get this:

```
pip install Pillow==5.3.0
'install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

does anyone know a solution or better yet an easier way to download pillow?

Comment: What is the relation of this with pycharm?

Comment: check if your pip is installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the command and it is working for me:

```
C:\Users>workon python37
(python37) C:\Users>pip install Pillow==5.3.0
Collecting Pillow==5.3.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/ea/305f61258278790706e69f01c53e107b0830ea5a4a69aa1f2c11fe605ed3/Pillow-5.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.6MB 3.9MB/s
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-5.3.0
You are using pip version 18.0, however, version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

You should check if **pip** is installed in your python3.7. It might be not even installed.

In your tags, you have mention **Pycharm** and in it, you are not installing packages with pip it has its own packages ocntrol ui.

[Pycharm package install guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

Comment: thanks for the help!